# Whenever gem Time.now always the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I have a `schedule.rb` file running database backups nightly. The code is as follows:

```
every :day, :at => '10:20pm' do
  fname = Time.now.strftime('%d_%m_%Y_dump.sql')
  command "pg_dump -f #{fname}"
  command "gzip #{fname}"
end
```

However, the files are not being updated and according to my cron log:

> gzip: 29_12_2015_dump.sql.gz already exists;  not overwritten
>
> gzip: 29_12_2015_dump.sql.gz already exists;  not overwritten

The log file was most recently updated January 8th. This would imply that `Time.now` is the same every time that whenever is being run, i.e. every day. This seems unlikely, what could be going on?

Comment: Do you use timecop or any similar gem?

Comment: no I don't use timecop.

Comment: What if you replace `Time.now` with `Date.today`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what the problem was: `whenever` writes its `schedule.rb` file to the crontab once, thus the ruby code within the file is only evaluated at that point and not every time the job is run. Thus the "timestamp" has a static value equal to the day it was written to the crontab.

Comment: What is the solution then?